# Azure App Service CPU is spiking. I think it's SNAT exhaustion. Looking for ways to optimize code

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, cpu-usage, azure-webapps

This is a .NET 3.1 web API, talking to a MySQL database, all hosted on an Azure.

I've implemented everything I can think of to help with this problem:

- I am using [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#consumption-patterns)
- I am utilizing [DB connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0/#dbcontext-pooling)
- I am [caching wherever approprate](https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/#how-to-solve-a-snat-port-exhaustion-issue-for-app-service)

The caching helped the most, and it is relatively stable at around 50% CPU under heavy load, but every once in a while it spikes to 100% and the connections fail.

I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Is scaling an option?

Comment: You might want to add some logging to enable you to see the cause of this. Enable Application Insights on the App Service (assumption there) and see what's happening.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

From the App Service specific, here are few things you could add and review to narrow-down the issue further (I understand you have implemented solution to tackle Application/code side of things):

Unsure on the App Service Plan (ASP) tier you're using, each worker instance in an app service plan is allocated a number of SNAT ports. If you spread your usage across more instances, you might get the SNAT port usage per instance below the recommended limit of 100 outbound connections, per unique remote endpoint.

So to avoid outbound TCP limits, you can either increase the size of your workers, or scale out horizontally. DFord also pointed out the same- scale-up/scale-out and see if it improves based on the requirement. You can scale-up ASP to quickly isolate the issue and scale-down as per your requirement.

Additionally to find more information:

You can use *App Service Diagnostics* to find SNAT port allocation information, and observe the SNAT ports allocation metric of an App Service site.

1. To access App Service diagnostics, navigate to your App Service web
   app  in the Azure portal.
2. In the left navigation, select Diagnose
   and solve problems.
3. Select Availability and Performance Category
4. Select SNAT Port Exhaustion tile in the list of available tiles under the category.

Checkout this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-intermittent-outbound-connection-errors#avoiding-the-problem) for more information.

[image]